# Adobe CQ5.5 how to create multiple CustomMultiField to be used in a single component

Tags: extjs, aem

I have a requirement which requires me to use a single dialog with two tabs. Each tab should have a CustomMultiField (multiple sets of four fields). I do not know anything about EXT JS. Can some one point me to right direction where I can find something about requirement as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built custom components without any explicit understanding of Ext JS.  To understand how to set up a dialog with tabs, look at the code for the `page` component in `/libs/foundation/component/page`.  A directory of all the xytpes you can use, like MultiField, is [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/widgets/xtypes.html).

Comment: I want to customize the multifield, something like two multi-multi fields in two tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that behave like one, but is not necessarily huge specific ExtJS component or custom xtype, and you do not want to dig hundreds of Adobe ‘support’ pages, trying to find some piece of useful doc.

You can simply use `multifield` xtype and write 4 pure JS listeners, that does what you need.